# How to measure the max load factor of a hash table python

Tags: python, hashmap

```
class HashMap:
    """ hashmap class """
    def __init__(self):
        self.max_length = 8
        self.max_load_factor = 0.8
        self.length = 0
        self.map = [None] * self.max_length
        self.keyslist = []

    def _get_hash(self, key):
        hash = 0
        for char in str(key):
            hash += ord(char)
        return hash % self.max_length

    def get(self, key, default=None):
        key_hash = self._get_hash(key)
        if self.map[key_hash] is not None:
            for pair in self.map[key_hash]:
                if pair[0] == key:
                    return pair[1]
        if self.map[key_hash] is None:
            return None

    def set(self, key, value):
        key_hash = self._get_hash(key)
        key_value = [key, value]
        self.keyslist.append(key)
        if self.map[key_hash] is None:
            self.length += 1
            self.map[key_hash] = list([key_value])
            if self.max_load_factor >= .8:
                self.rehash(self.capacity * 2)
            return True
        else:
            for pair in self.map[key_hash]:
                self.length += 1
                if pair[0] == key:
                    pair[1] = value
                    return True
            if self.max_load_factor >= .8:
                self.rehash(self.capacity * 2)
            self.map[key_hash].append(key_value)
            return True


    def capacity(self):
        return self.max_length  # return the current capacity --number of buckets-- in the map

    def rehash(self):
        self.map = [None] * (self.max_length * 2)
        return self.map
```

So i need a max load factor of .8, and when that occurs, i need to rehash the table (essentially making the map double the capacity)

But how exactly do i measure the load factor? is it the length of the current buckets? Because if you look at the set() method, after adding, if the load-factor >= 80%, i need to rehash the map into a map double its current capacity. however, how exactly do i measure the load factor?

Any help would be appreciated. I just need to know how to measure the load factor!

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you wanted:

```py
class HashMap:
    """ hashmap class """
    def __init__(self, max_length=8):
        self.max_length = max_length
        self.max_load_factor = 0.8
        self.length = 0
        self.map = [None] * self.max_length
        self.keyslist = []


    def _get_hash(self, key):
        hash = 0
        for char in str(key):
            hash += ord(char)
        return hash % self.max_length


    def get(self, key, default=None):
        key_hash = self._get_hash(key)
        if self.map[key_hash] is not None:
            for pair in self.map[key_hash]:
                if pair[0] == key:
                    return pair[1]
        if self.map[key_hash] is None:
            return None


    def _rehash_if_needed(self):
        if self.length >= self.max_load_factor * self.capacity():
            self._rehash(self.capacity() * 2) 


    def set(self, key, value):
        key_hash = self._get_hash(key)
        key_value = [key, value]
        self.keyslist.append(key)
        if self.map[key_hash] is None:
            self.length += 1
            self.map[key_hash] = list([key_value])
            self._rehash_if_needed()
            return True
        else:
            for pair in self.map[key_hash]:
                self.length += 1
                if pair[0] == key:
                    pair[1] = value
                    return True
            self.map[key_hash].append(key_value)
            self._rehash_if_needed()
            return True


    def capacity(self):
        return self.max_length


    def _rehash(self, new_capacity):
        # Create new hashmap with new capacity 
        new_hashmap = HashMap(new_capacity)
        # Insert all the keys in the new hashmap
        for key in self.keyslist:
            value = self.get(key)
            new_hashmap.put(key, value)

        # Copy all the fields of the new hashmap to this hashmap
        self.max_length = new_hashmap.max_length
        self.max_load_factor = new_hashmap.max_load_factor
        self.length = new_hashmap.length
        self.map = new_hashmap.map
        self.keyslist = new_hashmap.keyslist
```